# PHP execute python program with exec on raspberry pi

Tags: php, python, gpio

I am running an apache server with php installed on my raspberry pi 2 B+. In my php file I have the code

```
 echo exec("sudo chmod +x gpio.py && sudo python gpio.py 50");
```

which does not work. However, when I run this same command in the directory on the local machine, it works. I can also run like an ls

```
 echo exec("ls");
```

command and that works, but the command to run the python code doesn't    work. How can I go about fixing this issue? This python file sets up a GPIO and sets it to LOW. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

SUDOER FILE

```
 #
 # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/www/bash.sh
# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your Apache Server does not have sufficient permissions to execute the command. You could do a number of things, adding your `www-data` group to the "sudo list". This is accessible in `/etc/sudoers`.

Your original model may not work if the Apache group does not have complete sudo capabilities. One workaround may be to create a shell script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo chmod +x gpio.py && sudo python gpio.py 50 2>&1
```

Then change the PHP to the following:

```
echo exec("/path/to/my/script.sh");
```

You would want to add something along the lines of this to the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/my/script.sh
```

Although, take into account adding a web server to the sudo list is not something that's typically recommended, if you can get around it.

Comment: This still doesn't work :( I set the path to /var/www/gpio.py

Comment: how bout `echo exec("echo $SUDO_PASSWORD | sudo -S chmod +x gpio.py && sudo python gpio.py 50");` although it doesnt make much sense to change it to +x and still use python to execute...

Comment: I would even edit it to the following to see if you are getting some sort of error: `echo exec("sudo chmod +x gpio.py && sudo python gpio.py 50 2>&1");`

Comment: @Brandon White I'm still not getting anything.

Comment: @BrandonWhite I still cannot get this to work. I am executing /var/www/bash.sh in the php exec funtion. I tested my bash script and it works. I just added the contents of my sudoers file to the question.

Comment: Add your sudoers to the question, not the answer. Also, how are you certain it is not working? Are you expecting an output from the script of some sort? If so, I actually may need to update the shell script to appropriately echo the output from that file.

Comment: Furthermore, you may try the php command `shell_exec() ` as this will output the entire output, rather than just the last line from your program.

Comment: @Brandonwhite Ok, so I got it working but what I had to do was set the sudoer to ALL instead of the file path for the bash.sh file. Is there any way of getting the file path to work because that would be the preferred method because of security issues.